# Query throws ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier when using joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I've come across some weird behavior that's preventing me from setting up a query in the way I'd like to.  Would appreciate any ideas.  If there's any information about the tables that would be helpful, please let me know.  I looked through them and nothing jumped out at me that might cause this but nor did I know what I was looking for.  Here is the behavior.

This works fine:

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b,
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c,
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d
Where 
    b.friend_id = c.friend_id
    AND a.group_id = d.group_id
    AND b.group_cd = d.group_cd
```

But this returns ORA-00904: b.friend_id = c.friend_id: invalid identifier

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b,
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c
On
    b.friend_id = c.friend_id
Where 
    a.group_id = d.group_id
    AND b.group_cd = d.group_cd
```

This returns ORA-00904: b.group_cd = d.group_cd: invalid identifier

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c
On
    b.friend_id = c.friend_id
Join 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d
On 
    a.group_id = d.group_id
    AND b.group_cd = d.group_cd
```

And this works again:

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c
On
    b.friend_id = c.friend_id
Join 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d
On
    b.group_cd = d.group_cd
Where  
    a.group_id = d.group_id
```

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't mix old Oracle-type joins with proper ANSI ones, as the join order and scope becomes even less clear... stick to one or the other, preferably ANSI *8-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the `using` keyword which is designed for `join` on same column name

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C USING(friend_id)
Join 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d using(group_id)
where b.group_cd = d.group_cd;
```

Also make sure that you execute the other query with the right users, as an user that does not have correct permission will throw `invalid identifier`.

**Edit :** The actual problem is that you are joining `TABLE_C` with `TABLE_D` but the join condition refer to `TABLE_B` change it to

```
Select * 
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c using(friend_id)
Where 
    a.group_id = d.group_id
    AND b.group_cd = d.group_cd;
```

Apply the same logic for other queries, when doing a join, you do not join to a group of table, but to the last table mentionned in the `from` clause therefore it did not have access to `TABLE_B`.

For other people that might have an `invalid identifier` error, make sure your database is not case sensitive, else make sure to use the right case.

Comment: He already has code that runs successfully.  He is looking for an explanation of the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Another possibility would be the case sensitivity, but your both queries are written the same way..

Comment: That's totally it.  I did not realize joins work like this but it makes perfect sense now.  Thanks so much!  Fyi, I think the problem with the USING was that it should replace ON, not follow it

Comment: @philfo yes, with `using` keyword there must not have `ON` my mistake, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have run into the intricacy in SQL dealing with join scoping/precedence. Since I am not myself a database programmer, I can't really tell you why it works the way it does, but I do see some logic in the way the query parser is behaving.

In your first query, all the joins are cross joins. As a result, they should have the same precedence. So all the joined columns are known when the join is evaluated.

In the second query, you have a combination of cross joins and inner joins. If we assume that inner join has precedence over cross joins, then table c and d are joined before any other tables are added to the mix. So when you reference `b.friend_id` in the inner join, which is outside of the inner join, the query parser isn't able to use that column in evaluating the join.

In the third query, the inner join between tables b, c and d take precedence over the cross join. So column `a.group_id` isn't available in evaluating the inner join condition. When you take table a out of the inner join condition in the final query, the query no longer has a conflicting precedence.

Comment: They aren't really cross-joins; with the old comma-separated table syntax, Oracle uses the `where` conditions as join conditions. (Actually it still can with ANSI joins, but that's another story). But you're still right, C and D are joined first and B isn't in scope then.

Comment: Actually, the comma-separated list of tables is an implied cross join. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join. That's why this practice is very much discouraged for readability AND performance reasons.

Comment: From the same page: "The results of a cross join can be filtered by using a WHERE clause which may then produce the equivalent of an inner join." I agree it would be a cross-join without a `where`, but since there is one it's an inner join - though the terminology gets a bit awkward when you use ANSI terms for Oracle's syntax (even [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries006.htm) *8-) I'm largely splitting hairs.

Comment: You are correct that the results returned will be the same as an inner join, but the way that the query parser arrives at that result could be vastly different. If you are dealing with a very large dataset, having to load all the records, apply a cross join on all of them, then filter is going to result in a huge dataset in memory. Hopefully, the query parser would optimize the cross join into an inner join. If it does, then you are absolutely correct in saying that they are equivalent. Barring that assurance, I wouldn't say that a cross join with `WHERE` is the same as an inner join.

Comment: @bluecollarcoder: It's logically a cross join until the `where` condition is applied, but the database won't evaluate it that way. If you look at an explain plan for the queries from the OP, you won't see an Cartesian products. Databases have been evaluating joins in the `where` clause for a long time and are built to take them into account when optimizing the query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the mixing of join types. When you use comma-separated table in the `FROM` clause, each term is evaluated individually. Take the following example:

```
From 
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A a,
    SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B b,
    SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d
Join 
    SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c
On
    b.friend_id = c.friend_id
```

The database is trying to resolve `SCHEMA_A.TABLE_D d Join SCHEMA_C.TABLE_C c On b.friend_id = c.friend_id`. Within this scope, `b` has no meaning (it's a separate term).

For your third version, I get `"A"."GROUP_ID": invalid identifier`, which is also in-line with this explanation.

Ultimately the lesson you should take from this is not to mix join types.